# Arduino esp8266 restrict an IP address

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

How can I restrict/ban an IP from which my ESP8266 can receive packages. Is this even possible directly without some sort of proxy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No directly but this is the key:

> Is this even possible directly without some sort of proxy

If you are not limited from environment or the place where your system will be placed a good way to tackle this is to not expose the ESP to the public but rather keep it in your private network and proxy it from Apache2, NginX or whatever you like to the users.